# How to import existing json file into another json file

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a tsconfig.json file for my react project. I also wanted to create a tsconfig.test.json with the same features as tsconfig.json with an additional attribute. In case of something would be changed, I wanted to import and use the tsconfig.json file into tsconfig.test.json file. I searched but couldn't find a way to import a json file and use it directly into another json file. Is there any way to achieve it?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.test.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

I don't want to rewrite the tsconfig.code to tsconfig.test.json file . What I want is to import to code and add the esModuleInterop one.
I tried to import the tsconfig.json and spread into the other file but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PriyenMehta You are right I updated it with the code